# Check if user is admin or normal user? PHP $_session and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show different content if a user is admin(2), or noarmal user(1). Login works fine, but i don't know hot to check if a user have 'usertype' 1 or 2? I want to use PHP $_SESSION.

This is my login form:

```
<!-- Log in -->
<form method="post" action="authentication.php">
  <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="E-mail" required/>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/><br>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
</form>
```

This is my authentication.php:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
$userid     = $_POST['userid'];
$password   = $_POST['password'];

$dbc        = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'news');
if(!$dbc){
echo "Cannot connect to database";
exit;
}

$query      = "SELECT * FROM users_tbl WHERE email = '$userid' AND password = sha1('$password')";
$result     = $dbc->query($query);
if($result->num_rows)
{
$_SESSION['valid_user'] = $userid;
}
$dbc->close();
}
if(isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])){
header("location:prefs.php");
}else{
header("location:login.php");
echo 'Error';
}
```

This is what i have tried:

```
    <?php 

    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('news');

    $sql = "SELECT users_tbl.usertype FROM users_tbl";
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    $user = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user['user']; 
    $_SESSION['usertype'] = $user['usertype'];        

    if($_SESSION['user']['usertype'] == 2)
    {?>
    <h1>Only admin stuff</h1>

    <$? }//Endif user is admin(2) ?>
```

Maybe instead of doing the query for everytime to check if a user is admin, i could save a $_SESSION['usertype'], and then use this to check if a user is 2, for admin, maybe when a user is loggin in? But i do not know how to do this. I'm quite new at this.

Comment: you need to call `session_start()` before you start using the `$_SESSION` vars, that could be one reason it's not setting them.

Comment: session_start() is at the top of every page to check if $_SESSION['valid_user'] isset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
   if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 2)
{
   //do stuff here 
}
 if ($_SESSION['usertype']) == 1)

 {
 //do stuff here 
 }
```

edit :
if you dont want write so many stuff and you want just include admin stuff inside this one of users just do this

```
  if ($_SESSION['usertype']) == 1 or $_SESSION['usertype']) == 2)

   {
              //do stuff here for them both admin and users
         if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 2 ) 
                                   {
                                  //do extra stuff here for only admin 
                                    }
   }
```

Comment: I have tried this, but when i log in as admin or normal user, it is the same content?

Comment: no just do different content on each if , if admin , write stuff for him and same for users

Comment: look my updated answer , if you want dont want write double stuff for them , just include extra staff for admin

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is an old question, however I have spent the last week searching the internet looking for an answer to this question as I have had a similar issue. "echo_Me" had the answer, but I see some incorrect syntax. After toying around with it on a localserver, this is what I did.

```
if($_SESSION['usertype']) == 1 or $_SESSION['usertype']) ==2)
//> start           end <                          end <    < end
 {
    //do stuff here for them both admin and users
    if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 2)
     {
      //Do other stuff for usertype 2
     }
  }
```

You have more End Parenthesis then you do start ones.
I set all of the session variables I need when I run the login script for my website. So if I need a session variable, here is how I would handle it:

```
if($_SESSION['user']['usertype'] == 1 OR $_SESSION['user']['usertype'] == 2) { ?>
// Do Stuff for normal user and admin
    <?php } if($_SESSION['user']['usertype'] == 2) { ?>
      // DO Stuff for admin only
    <?php } ?>
```

As you can see, the first if statement only has one set of parenthesis. And really, you can remove some of the php code, and just do regular html/css markup then the if statement for usertype of 2 for stuff for admin.

```
<!-- HTML Markup for both Admin and Regular Users Goes Here above if statement -->
<?php if($_SESSION['user']['usertype'] == 2 { ?>
  // Markup for Admin only
<?php } ?>
```

Also, I would recommend not having the password set in the session variables. In that code, you may have it not do that, I am just unfamiliar with mysqli as I use PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your user type with session variable

Once logged in  you need to check with db with the user type for 1 or 2 and store that variable with session variable like $_SESSION['user_type'].

So based on that you can track.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a column with **user type** to that table.
 Check the value of that column while fetching data from the table. If the value is **admin**, show the text otherwise not.